# How to start local server with symfony 5 or downgrade version to 4.4?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony5, symfony-4.4

I started a new project in new Symfony 5 and i can't open my local server.

On Symfony 4.4 the command PHP `bin/console server:run` is OK,

But with Symfony 5 the command appears not to be defined...

```
C:\Users\Chris\Code\api-test> php bin/console server:run
Command "server:run" is not defined.
Do you want to run "server:dump" instead?  (yes/no) [no]:
```

So how to downgrade or start the local server?

Comment: This command is deprecated from Symfony 4.4 and has been removed on Symfony 5 [read here](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/setup/built_in_web_server.html), you can use [Symfony Local Web Server](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/symfony_server.html) instead. Please note that the link you provide above is for actual web server application configuration, which can be used in production. This command is for development only.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The Web Server Bundle is **not included** with Symfony 5.

But you can simply `require` it and install it separately.

E.g.:

```sh
composer require symfony/web-server-bundle 4.4
```

**It is important that you specify the version (4.4)**, because otherwise it will attempt to install version 5 (which does not exist, and it will fail).

After that you'll be able to run `bin/console server:run` as you used to do.

---

Otherwise, you may use the [Symfony CLI](https://symfony.com/download) as well. This is an executable binary which includes the Symfony Server by default. Then you may run `symfony server:start` or the better know alias `symfony serve` to start the local webserver.

Read more about Symfony's server [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/symfony_server.html#getting-started).

---

You can also use the [built-in web server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) in the PHP runtime. Just go to your project's root directory and run:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public/
```

It's not a fully featured webserver, but for developing purposes it is usually more than enough.

Comment: This should be markes as the right answer. Thanks pal

Comment: should be noted that server:run provides no significative advantage over builtin php's web server, and server:start does not run with symfony 5.*+

Comment: how change `symfony`  binary php version? cause now it uses my old PHP version.

Answer (score 9):

For running a local web server you can now use Symfony Client, or simply 'Symfony'.

1. [Download](https://symfony.com/download) the binary and install it globally.
2. Open a terminal and run once: `symfony server:ca:install`. This will install a local SSL certificate authority that allows you to run the local webserver on `https://`.
3. Inside the terminal, move into your project directory and run `symfony serve`. A local webserver will start; by default on `https://localhost:8000/`.

If you wish to run the webserver on another port you can use `symfony serve --port=8080` (in this case port `8080`). For the most useful commands Symfony Client has to offer, simply run `symfony`. To see all available commands run `symfony help`.

Answer (score 8):

I am using symfony 5 and I just replace the former command `php bin/console server:run`" by `php -S localhost:3000 -t public` and it works in a similar way.

`-t` public to indicate the targeted file.

Comment: Thanks. This solution is working on Symfony 5

Answer (score 1):

1. `php -S localhost:9000 -t public` | PHP Inbuild Server / -t set to the public dir
2. `php bin/console server:run` | Only for Symfony 4.* and below
3. `symfony serve` | Symfony Server symfony ServeBundle

- To run `symfony serve` you must first install the ServerBundle: `composer require symfony/web-server-bundle`
- The really really really cool think is that you can use https out of the box. You need only run `symfony server:ca:install`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using symfony 5,4 and I just use command

```
$ symfony serve
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please share more details. This command was already provided in some other answers. Is there any need to duplicate them? If you want to share new insights, please do so by adding them to your answer

Answer (score -1):

You need to install symfony by running theses commands:
cd my-project
composer require symfony/web-server-bundle --dev
And run the server
php bin/console server:run